# Lsp-mode getting weird error trying to M-x lsp

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

(See updates at end of question)

I installed lsp-mode for php and I also installed intelephense (so the command `intelephense` is available in the terminal)

I can open a PHP file and do `M-x lsp-mode` and this succeeds.

Then I do `M-x lsp` and got following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function -andfn)
  (-andfn #'lsp--supports-buffer\? #'lsp--server-binary-present\?)
  (lsp--filter-clients (-andfn #'lsp--supports-buffer\? #'lsp--server-binary-present\?))
  (let (clients (matching-clients (lsp--filter-clients (-andfn #'lsp--supports-buffer\? #'lsp--server-binary-present\?)))) (cond (matching-clients (if (setq lsp--buffer-workspaces (or (and (not ...) (lsp--tr$
  (progn (let (clients (matching-clients (lsp--filter-clients (-andfn #'lsp--supports-buffer\? #'lsp--server-binary-present\?)))) (cond (matching-clients (if (setq lsp--buffer-workspaces (or (and ... ...) (l$
  (if (buffer-file-name) (progn (let (clients (matching-clients (lsp--filter-clients (-andfn #'lsp--supports-buffer\? #'lsp--server-binary-present\?)))) (cond (matching-clients (if (setq lsp--buffer-workspac$
  lsp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(lsp nil)
  call-interactively(lsp record nil)
  command-execute(lsp record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "lsp" "lsp")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "lsp" "lsp")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Please help? What does this mean and how do I resolve it?

--

Edit: I reinstalled lsp-mode using MELPA. Now, `M-x lsp-mode` still succeeds, and `M-x lsp` gives the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function -compose)
  -compose(lsp--client-path->uri-fn lsp--workspace-client)
  lsp--path-to-uri("/home/myusername/.emacs.d/index.sqlite")
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0xaf28e9>)()
  funcall(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0xaf28e9>))
  eval((funcall #'#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0xaf28e9>)))
  custom-initialize-reset(lsp-serenata-index-database-uri (funcall #'#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0xaf28e9>)))
  custom-declare-variable(lsp-serenata-index-database-uri (funcall #'#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0xaf28e9>)) "The location to store the index database.\nNote tha..." :group lsp-ser$
  byte-code("\301\302\303\304 \305\306\307!\310\311\312\313&\10!\210\314\315\316\317\320\321\322\323\324\325&\11\210\326\327!\210\330\331\332\333\334DD\335\336\337\340\341\320\315\324\342$
  require(lsp-php nil t)
  #f(compiled-function (package) #<bytecode 0xa6b1b9>)(lsp-php)
  mapc(#f(compiled-function (package) #<bytecode 0xa6b1b9>) (ccls lsp-actionscript lsp-ada lsp-angular lsp-ansible lsp-bash lsp-beancount lsp-clangd lsp-clojure lsp-cmake lsp-crystal lsp-$
  seq-do(#f(compiled-function (package) #<bytecode 0xa6b1b9>) (ccls lsp-actionscript lsp-ada lsp-angular lsp-ansible lsp-bash lsp-beancount lsp-clangd lsp-clojure lsp-cmake lsp-crystal ls$
  lsp--require-packages()
  lsp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(lsp nil)
  call-interactively(lsp record nil)
  command-execute(lsp record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "lsp" "lsp")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "lsp" "lsp")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: `-andfn` is defined in `Dash.el`. Try to make sure you installed it successfully. Or reinstall lsp and all its dependency packages.

Comment: @TianshuWang Thank you for your help. I reinstalled lsp-mode from MELPA. It still didn't work but the error message is different (I edited my question with it)

Comment: `-compose` is still defined in `Dash.el`. So I think the problem is still there. Try to reinstall `Dash.el` or try to replicate with minimal configuration (see lsp-mode issue template).